# DevDemon Forms - Entry Linked breaks publishing/editing entries

Tags: forms, devdemon

When using a Forms channel field, pressing submit after creating/editing an entry just kicks you to the main page. This was working for a while but a client just notified me that they can't edit/create content.

Versions:
Forms: 3.5.2
ExpressionEngine: 2.7.2

Comment: ** Edit ** I was able to fix this by going to Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Security and Sessions and setting the User Session Type to Cookies only.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by going to Admin -> Security and Privacy -> Security and Sessions and setting the  User Session Type to Cookies only.